# Java generics return object instead of list

Tags: java, generics

Out of pure curiosity, having :

```
List bigList = new ArrayList();
```

Why this code compiles :

```
List<List> partitions = Lists.partition(bigList , 10);
for (List partition : partitions) {}
```

And this does not :

```
for (List partition : Lists.partition(bigList , 10)) {}
```

?

Signature of partition method :

```
<T> List<List<T>> partition(List<T> list, int size)
```

Comment: Why are you using `List` as a raw type? What should the type parameter be in the declaration of `bigList`?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I would just like to strongly discourage using raw types (`List` instead of `List<String>` etc.) unless you know what you're doing have a good reason to do so.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using? Also, are you using any IDE? B'coz the first version itself doesn't compile on my PC.

Comment: More important, what is the error message?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy: It's presumably the [Guava class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html).

Comment: @Bax Whenever you are using some 3rd party library, say so clearly. I assume you are using Guava here.

Comment: @Rohit Jain I've put there the signature of the used method, you can write it on your own.

Answer (score 3):

`List<List> partitions = Lists.partition(bigList , 10);`

`Lists.partition(bigList , 10)`

These two lines will do the exact same thing during runtime. The difference is during compile time where the former will be forcefully interpreted as a `List<List>` (with a compiler warning because it's a potentially dangerous thing to do) while the latter is assumed to be a raw `List`.

When iterating over a `List<List>`, the elements will be assumed to be `List`. For raw types though, the elements will be assumed to be `Object`. Therefore, this breaks:

`for (List partition : Lists.partition(bigList , 10)) {}`

...because you're trying to assign an `Object` to a `List` variable.

I would also like to reiterate what I mentioned in a comment: Don't use raw types unless you have a *very* good reason to do so and fully understand the risks and consequences of doing so. Due to Java's type erasure, using raw types will make you lose all guarantees that a list contains what it claims to contain, potentially making the entire program crash if the wrong type is encountered.

Comment: Once again : "Out of pure curiosity", thank you for the answer

Comment: @Bax: Nothing wrong with asking something just out of curiosity; I occasionally do so myself. I'm just trying to make sure you don't also needlessly use raw types in a serious project "out of curiosity". :)

Comment: Well ... when e.g. Hibernate returns you a raw List there's nothing you can do besides dealing with it, so it's not always our choice to use or not raw collections.